# how can multiple users send message with rabbitmq using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-messaging

My aim: i have multiple jobs(Processes) running parallely (seperate threads). i want to implement messaging so that each process can send message(if required) to rabbitmq Server.
 now i have this

```
@Configuration
public class SenderConfiguration {

    String content = "";
    String host = "";
    String port = "";
    String userName = "";
    String password = "";
    String queueName = "";
    InputStream input = null;

    public SenderConfiguration() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("R.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH");
            host = prop.getProperty("messaging.host");
            port = prop.getProperty("messaging.port");
            userName = prop.getProperty("messaging.userName");
            password = prop.getProperty("messaging.password");
            queueName = prop.getProperty("messaging.queue");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setRoutingKey(this.queueName);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(
                this.host);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(userName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ScheduledProducer scheduledProducer() {
        return new ScheduledProducer();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor postProcessor() {
        return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    static class ScheduledProducer {

        @Autowired
        private volatile RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

        private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
        public void sendMessage(String message) {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("Roxy " + counter.incrementAndGet());
        }
    }

}
```

and to call this from one of my operation

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SenderConfiguration.class);
```

shall i make it abstract class and my every operation /process should extend it ? what would be best approach ?
 and can i make above process any better?

Answer (score 1):

Just use single class with property placeholders...

Use

```
@Value("${messaging.host}")
String host;
```

etc.

No need for a subclass for each.

Comment: ok. i did those changes :). calling send message from all my classes would be fine right ? or i can make it any better?

Comment: Your question is too vague.